# how to deploy web app to tomcat on google cloud computer engine

Tags: tomcat, google-cloud-platform

Do any one know how to deploy web application to tomcat on google cloud computer engine？
I can't find document about it 2 days.
Can any body give me a hint？
thanks~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance (I suggest Debian) and access it by ssh and install jdk, tomcat and deploy you app. I do that with a script that run on start up and takes the war file of cloud storage. Another way is create an image after the manual configuration.

Comment: can you share the script ? anyway, thank you very much

Comment: How do the same but from CICD pipeline? I mean compute instance is present and an artifact in the cloud storage and I want to deploy it to that VM.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/), search for 'Tomcat' and you will have an instance with Devian 9, Apache And JDK installed and ready to be used.

Adding the pertinent documentation to complement previous answer:

- [Create instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance)
- [SSH to instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance)
- [Running Startup Scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)